# How to get bundle information through RESTlet script in Netsuite suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to get bundle version in which installed on target accounts using script.

ex:
There is way to get bundle id in suitescript 1.0 like below

```
nlapiGetContext().getBundleId()
```

like these is there any way to get bundle id, version etc on installed accounts through RESTlet script.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the apis in the N/runtime module:

```
var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
var bundleArr = scriptObj.bundleIds;
```